# How to deal with footnotes in cited sections?

Tags: formatting, citations, footnotes

When citing a section from another work, and that cited section has a footnote, how would you go about including the footnote in your citation?

Should I turn the footnote of the cited section into a footnote in my text? Or should I turn it simply into another cited section? Should I remove the footnote marker in the cited section? Should I leave the footnote marker in, and have the footnote refer to that other cited section in which I refer to the footnote? And if I turn it into a footnote, how would I mark that it is part of the cited text, and not a comment added to that cited text by me?

The problem is exacerbated in that my text has a running number of footnotes, but the footnote numbering in the cited section obviously does not fit into that numbering - my own footnotes are at number 190 or somesuch, and the footnote number in the cited text is 6. Should I replace the number used in the cited text by 191 to fit into the footnote numbering of my text? Just keep it as an odd one out in my footnote section (i.e. 189, 190, 6, 192, 193..., or 189, 190, 6, 191, 192...)?

Answer (score 0):

**1**

If you want to quote text that has a footnote, quote the text without the superscript number (i.e. as if it had no footnote).

Example source:

> > This is some<sup>3</sup> text.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>3</sup> This is the footnote.

Example quotation:

> Ben wrote: "This is some text." (2023, p. 45)

**2**

If you want to quote a footnote, indicate the footnote by writing "n" and the footnote number after the page number, e.g. "... p. 45n3" for footnote 3 on page 45 of your source.

Example source:

> This is some<sup>3</sup> text.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>3</sup> This is the footnote.

Example quotation:

> Ben wrote: "This is the footnote." (2023, p. 45n3)

**3**

If you want to cite both, combine the two:

> Ben wrote that "[t]his is some text" (2023, p. 45) and explained in a footnote that "[t]his is the footnote" (2023, p. 45n3).

Answer (score 0):

APA allows you to [remove footnote or endnote callouts](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/quotations/changes) from a quote entirely, which I feel is the most elegant and clear option. If the footnote provided some relevant details, you can incorporate that information into the text outside the quote. If the footnote was there because you're citing a secondary source, you should use the primary source instead.